# How to align CSS grid child to top of grid

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I'm trying to layer to grid children. I have a sidebar that's layered over a full height hero image that spans the entire width of the grid so that the sidebar overlays it. I can't seem to figure out how to align the grid child containing the image to the top of the viewport.

https://codepen.io/coreybruyere/pen/jQqZdp

```
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

.section.hero {
  padding:0;

  img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

#left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 10;
}

// This should be aligned to the top
#right {
  background-color: beige;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Comment: it's working fine on JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7mgz4dfh/) but not on codepen

Comment: Sorry you must of grabbed a copy while I was working on it. Check this jsfiddle out https://jsfiddle.net/7mgz4dfh/

Comment: in this case try to put all your code here to avoid seeing different version while you are editing your codepen

Comment: you share the same fiddle ... btw you are probably looking for `grid-column: span 1;` ?

Comment: I'm done editing my Codepen. There should be an image beneath the sidebar spanning the full width of the grid. https://codepen.io/coreybruyere/pen/jQqZdp

Comment: don't edit your codepen, add the code inside the question ... we need everything within the question

Comment: don't edit your codepen, add the code inside the question ... we need everything within the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with this CSS. Needed to specify values for `grid-column-start`, `grid-column-end`, and `grid-row-start` on the child elements.

```
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
}

.section.hero {
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

#right {
  background-color: beige;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sidebar to be 25% and the image to take the other 75%, then use `grid`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
}

.section.hero {
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100vh;
}

#right {
  background-color: beige;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="section">
    <p>This should not scroll</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="section hero">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/2000/2000" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the image to be full width, then you don't need to use `grid`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#right {
  background-color: beige;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="section">
    <p>This should not scroll</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="section hero">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/2000/2000" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: avoid the use of `//` as a comment, in CSS we use `/* */`. You may get a lot of issue like the OP is having

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't span the full width. If you inspect element on the right element you should see that it takes up the full width of the grid

Comment: // Is completely valid when using Sass

Comment: @CoreyBruyere converted to CSS it's no more valid, which is the case here .. the snippet allow only CSS not SASS

Comment: I need to use grid in this particular case. I know there's a way to overlay items

Comment: I'm really not sure why you need to use grid if one element is full width and the other is 25%.

Comment: I was modifying an existing template and am just adding a modifier CSS class do add a few properties